# How to add onclick event with setstate in react plotly.js scatter chart?

Tags: plotly

This is my JSX Codes Here.

```
<Plot
   data={data}
   config ={{
      scrollZoom: true,
    }}
   onClick ={(e) => {
    const { points } = e;
    setDefectIndex(points[0].data.info[points[0].pointIndex].ndefectIndex);
   }}
   layout={{ width: 500, height: 600, title: 'DVS Monitoring System', autoSize: true }}
 />
```

and I defined state variables

```js
const [defectIndex, setDefectIndex] = useState(0);
```

But when i'm click scatter points with setstate, chart's zoom is reset. I want to zoom don't reset when i'm click with setstate.

How can I reserve this problem?